# How to set sql request correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get data from column `meta_key - 'artikul'` and `meta_key='_thumbnail_id'`.

What I'm doing wrong?

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key='artikul'
AND meta_key='_thumbnail_id'";`

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` only works on one row.  So, the condition is never true.

I think you want:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key IN ('artikul', '_thumbnail_id')
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This returns posts that have the two keys.  This assumes that you don't have duplicate key values on a post.  If so, then use:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key) = 2
```

Comment: Actually, the full request is     $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key IN ('artikul', '_thumbnail_id') GROUP BY post_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2, AND id = ".$id." AND post_id = ".$id."";     And I get wrong data :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key='artikul') OR (meta_key='_thumbnail_id')
```

Comment: My full reauest    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta WHERE id = ".$id." AND post_id = ".$id."  AND (meta_key='artikul') OR (meta_key='_thumbnail_id') "     gives me a lot of unnecessary data((

Comment: Please specify what data are you looking for

Comment: I want to get this :          echo '{"id":' . $row['ID']. ',"post_type":"' . $row['post_type']. '","post_title":"' . $row['post_title']. '","post_id":' . $row['post_id']. ',"thumbnail_id":' . $row['??']. ',"artikul":"' . $row['??'] .'"}';